# Send the string data with the image upload using httprequest in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlconnection

I just want to send the date with this request:

```
var variables:String = "picture_title=" + pictit + "&"
variables += "picture_desc=" + picdes + "&"
variables += "category=" + tagfinal
```

I want to pass the above value along with the image file. The below code is working properly for the image upload but I am not able to add additional parameter to this code which used to send the string data to the php file.

```
var imageData :NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imagenReduced, 1.0);       
var request: NSMutableURLRequest?
let HTTPMethod: String = "POST"
var timeoutInterval: NSTimeInterval = 60
var HTTPShouldHandleCookies: Bool = false

request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request!.HTTPMethod = HTTPMethod
request!.timeoutInterval = timeoutInterval
request!.HTTPShouldHandleCookies = HTTPShouldHandleCookies

let boundary = "----------SwIfTeRhTtPrEqUeStBoUnDaRy"
let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)"
request!.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")
var body = NSMutableData();

let tempData = NSMutableData()
let fileName = filenames + ".jpg" //"prueba.jpg"
let parameterName = "userfile"

let mimeType = "application/octet-stream"

tempData.appendData("--\(boundary)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
let fileNameContentDisposition = fileName != nil ? "filename=\"\(fileName)\"" : ""
let contentDisposition = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(parameterName)\"; \(fileNameContentDisposition)\r\n"
tempData.appendData(contentDisposition.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
tempData.appendData("Content-Type: \(mimeType)\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
tempData.appendData(imageData)
tempData.appendData("\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

body.appendData(tempData)

body.appendData("\r\n--\(boundary)--\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

request!.setValue("\(body.length)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
request!.HTTPBody = body

var vl_error :NSErrorPointer = nil
var responseData  = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request,returningResponse: nil, error:vl_error)

var results = NSString(data:responseData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
println("finish \(results)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to do it with well-known [Alomafire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) library. Mattt and community has made a good job polishing that library.
There you will find method you are looking for, including passing image to server with some parameters. What you are looking for in particular, is this:

```
    Alamofire.upload(
    .POST,
    "http://httpbin.org/post",
    multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(fileURL: unicornImageURL, name: "unicorn")
        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(fileURL: rainbowImageURL, name: "rainbow")
    },
    encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .Success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                debugPrint(response)
            }
        case .Failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
        }
    }
)
```